# JQuery add textarea inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add textarea dynamically inside a div using JQuery & have following code:

```
@{    
    string emailText = ViewBag.email as string;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var textArea = $('<textarea style="padding-left:100px" />');
        emailText = emailText.replace("$[Group Custom Text]$", textArea);
        $("#divConfirmation").append(emailText);
    });
</script>

<div id="divAppointmentConfirmation"></div>
```

Problem is I get string value "[object Object]" instead of HTML control (textarea).

Comment: textArea is a jQuery object. I don't think you can replace a string by an object, unless it has a toString method.

Comment: That's as it should be. See the [replaceWith() docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/). Try putting the HTML straight into there, or use `replaceWith()`

Comment: replace a string with a string, not with an object.

Comment: Actually there is absolutly no point creating a jQuery object for that, even if $() is sexy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because `textArea` is a jQuery object.

And `({}).toString()` is `"[object Object]"`.

Use `outerHTML` to get its html.

```
emailText = emailText.replace("$[Group Custom Text]$", textArea[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it need a string as parameter. You can try this:

```
emailText.replace("$[Group Custom Text]$", textArea[0].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

check the following sentences:

```
$("#divConfirmation").append(emailText);

<div id="divAppointmentConfirmation"></div>
```

you can trivially observed that divConfirmation isn't divAppointmentConfirmation correct it too.